# I'm trying to perform certain pattern matching using python's re module

Tags: python, regex

```
Text = " If I can stop one heart from breaking,

I shall not live in vain;

If I can ease one life the aching,

Or cool one pain,

Or help one fainting robin

Unto his nest again,

I shall not live in vain."
```

**Problem:**

If the pattern has characters `ai` or `hi`, replace the next three characters with `*\*`.

I have tried using re.search() and re.sub() numerous times but I'm not able to figure out the logic to replace the next three characrers.

**Expected Output:**

If I can stop one heart from breaking,

I shall not live in vain;

If I can ease one life the achi*\*

Or cool one pain,

Or help one fai*\*ng robin

Unto hi*\*est again,

I shall not live in vain.

My code:

```
match_res = re.search(r"ai|hi",poem).group()
```

**I'm not able extract "hi"
I'm also not able to get the desired output**

Comment: Did you try anything yet ?

Comment: I have but all I'm able to do is find ai

Comment: You say 3 characters but the expected output only shows 2. Is it 2 or 3?

Comment: Sorry, for the mistake i have edited the question

Comment: Does this work for you: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QOe

Comment: Wow. this looks so simple. thanks

Comment: You're very welcome, GL!

Comment: @PedroLobito why \1 in the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `re` module will work for this, if you use a positive lookbehind:

```
your_text = "If I can ease one life the aching,"
re.sub("(?<=[ah]i).{3}", "***", your_text)
```

**Output**

```
'If I can ease one life the achi***'
```

**Explanation**

`(?<=[ah]i)` is a positive lookbehind, which will match only when the preceding two characters match the pattern `[ah]i`

`.{3}` matches any three characters (except newlines)

Comment: This code works perfectly, what does the ?<= signify here?

Comment: @vishalborana it's a positive look behind. Normally, regex patterns will "consume" the pattern they match, so you can't use them again. However, lookahead and lookbehinds will allow you to "peek" at a pattern without consuming it https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html